# Is it possible to edit and preview Shopify Liquid code without using Shopify?

Tags: html, css, ruby, shopify, liquid

I'm starting to use Shopify and am using a theme on Shopify and was wondering if I could edit a theme outside of Shopify?

My reasoning is, I'd like to use Livestyles (App that let's you preview changes instantly) but if that doesn't work, at least I can refresh faster.  Right now, previewing changes takes a little longer than I would like.

I know you can export the theme, but what about editing and viewing it?
My real question is how do developers customize themes?

Comment: They used to have an offline app, but that was years ago, not sure if that's still working even if you found it.

Answer (score 1):

You can install and use [Shopify's Desktop Theme Editor](https://apps.shopify.com/desktop-theme-editor), which allows you to work on themes locally. You can therefore use your code editor of choice and escape from working inside Shopify and on live projects. It's not amazing, but it will certainly allow you to do what you ask.

You can also set up a [Partner Account](https://app.shopify.com/services/partners/signup/). It is free and lets you experiment with themes for various projects.

Combine these two, and you have a reasonable environment for theme development.